# Trouble with calling method

Tags: java, integer-division

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

   for (double f=0; f<=20;f++) {
      System.out.println(f+":Degrees Fahrenheit converted to Celsius = "+ celsius(f));
   }
}

public static double celsius (double fahrenheit) {
    double cels=(fahrenheit-32)/(5/9);
    return cels;
}
```

With this program I'm trying to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius, and when I call method Celsius to my main when I run the program the end result for Celsius is always -infinity. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The question has already been answered well.  But as a note, you can just `return (fahrenheit-32.0)/(5.0/9.0);`  You don't actually need the `cels` variable.

Comment: please use for the iterating variable in your for-loop an integer!

Answer (score 4):

You're doing int division which always returns an int. For example `5/9` returns 0.

Instead use double division `5.0/9.0`

For your code:

```
public static double celsius (double fahrenheit) {
    return (fahrenheit - 32) / (5.0 / 9.0);
}
```

We should probably close this question as a duplicate as it's been asked many many times. For example: [fahrenheit-to-celsius-conversion-yields-only-0-0-and-0-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325882/fahrenheit-to-celsius-conversion-yields-only-0-0-and-0-0)

Answer (score 2):

`(5/9)` is an integer division, it always returns `0`.

It should be: `(5.0/9.0)`